Samsung Note 10 plus no 3G connection
Kindly I have this issue with my Note 10 plus quite a while and trying to fix it, but sadly still did not find the solution.
After having N975F/DS for a year, when the phone goes to 3g network it loses the signal and gives a message no network connection. as a result, to receive calls and sms I need to stay in 2g only mode, and the data I use a wifi connection, but cannot use lte as if I got a call the phone will go to 3g, resulting unreachable message to the caller.
I started to search the internet for a solution and after a long search I have concluded that I need to flush the device. I have downloaded the latest version from "sammobile" and as the country that I live in does not exist I have used the closest country.
An hour ago I have finished flushing the rom of the device using odin and after getting back the phone to work, tried from auto mode (4g/3g/2g) mode to make a call, from 4g it went to 3g and the shock, same issue cannot connect to the 3g network.
I have tried the sim card in another phone and it worked smoothly with no issues, and as well I have tried another sim card from a normally working phone in this phone and the issue exists.
Kindly I need help.

In which country are you and which mobile network do you use? In a lot of countries 3G services have already been shut down, in some even 2G services are no longer available.

In Jordan, still they provide the three layers: 2G, 3G and LTE

If 3G is still provided it could be a problem with the used frequencies. Each device only supports a limited number of frequency bands and your mobile network provider is only allowed to use a certain set of frequencies and these frequencies have to be split up between 2G/3G/4G. In case of bad luck your MNO provides 3G services on frequencies your phone doesn't support.

First of all, I thank you for your help.
I cannot find a way to pull the supported frequencies that the phone has from the phone itself, the only way is from gsmarena.
I have G-NetTrack Lite app installed on both phones: Note 10 plus and A3 (2017). In all scenarios that I do in A3 that forces frequency change, all of them is supported in Note 10+

Cannot handle ARFCN numbers: 10737 and 10762

In gsmarena it states that the phone supports the 2100MHz band and checking the frequencies of ARFCN 10737 and 10762 are in the range for both uplink and downlink, so I cannot isolate that the issue is from the phone or from the network!
